# How to re-render import component on state change

Tags: react-native

I have made two component (parent & child) & import the child component containing react-native modal

I have render child component after state change, it renders first time but on second time, it doesn't work.

Parent.js file is as follows:

```
import react, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import ActionModal from './ActionModal';

export default class Parent extends Component {
 constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = { tabclicked: false }
 }

 actiontabclicked = () => {
   this.setState({ tabclicked: true });
 }

 render(){
   return (
     <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.actiontabclicked()} }>
     <Text> MOVE</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      { (this.state.tabclicked) ? <ActionModal /> : null }

     </View>
   )
 }
}
```

ActionModal.js file code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Modal, Text, TouchableHighlight, View, Alert} from 'react-native';

export default class ActionModal extends Component {

  constructor(){
   super();
   this.state = { modalVisible: true }
  }

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
        <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        visible={this.state.modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => { this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)}}>
        <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
          <View>
            <Text>Hello World!</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
   );
 }
}
```

ActionModal opens first time but not second time, I think this is because state becomes true but after close modal it doesn't reset.
How can I achieve that ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're not being so clear with what you want to achieve, if you want to achieve this behaviour of tapping > dismiss > tap again > shows
you should make something like this on your `setModalVisible` function:

```
setModalState = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
            modalVisible: !prevState.modalVisible
          })
  }
```

This will change the state opposite to what it was. If you want to have more control maybe you can create two functions `setModalOpen` and `setModalClosed`

Maybe you can use props on the child component when `onRequestClose` is triggered to pass this function to the parent and there you can call `setModalClosed`, the way you have to do it is to make a callback with the given props (look for passing props to parent in react on the internet, it's quite simple)

Hope I could help